# What are the set of cosets of an induced graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity

I am reading [Hau Huang's proof of the sensitivity conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00847) and I am a bit confused by the group theory notation. I would like to understand the following line:

> Recall that $Q^n$ denotes the n-dimensional cube graph. For an induced graph $H$ of $Q^n$, let $Q^n-H$ denote the subgraph of $Q^n$ induced on the vertex set $V(Q^n) \setminus V(H)$.

I am assuming that $V(Q^n) \setminus V(H)=\{V(Q^n)h:h\in V(H)\}$, but what does $gh$ mean when $g$ and $h$ are vertices?

Am I interpreting this correctly, and if so what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

This is not $/$, the quotient operator, but $\setminus$ the "set difference" operator.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

In particular, this has nothing to do with cosets or group theory.